# Covariance, contravariance and all that jazz

Tags: category-theory

For the love of God, can someone explain to me the difference between functors of the form $\mathcal{C}^{\text{op}}\to \mathcal{D}$, $\mathcal{C}\to \mathcal{D}^{\text{op}}$ and $\mathcal{C}^{\text{op}}\to \mathcal{D}^{\text{op}}$?

I really do not understand how to tell what kind of functor an assignment gives: say that I know how a functor $F$  is defined on the objects and morphisms of a domain category $\mathcal{C}$, and I want to know its variance (is this a proper word?). Suppose that I do the usual thing, where I consider a morphism $f:A\to B$ in $\mathcal{C}$, and I find that $F(f)$ goes the other way, namely $F(f):F(B)\to F(A)$ in the target category $\mathcal{D}$. Is then $F$ a functor $\mathcal{C}^{\text{op}}\to\mathcal{D}$ or a functor $\mathcal{C}\to\mathcal{D}^{\text{op}}$?

Comment: A **contravariant functor** $\mathcal C\to\mathcal D$ is a covariant functor is by definition a (covariant) functor $\mathcal C^{op}\to\mathcal D$. A functor $\mathcal C\to\mathcal D^{op}$ is a covariant functor from $\mathcal C$. These two functors are given by the same data, but the whole point of category theory is that domains and codomains of transformations actually *matter* and lead to non-trivial differences in the statements of results.

Comment: Yes, exactly, that's what I thought - which is why I was a bit skeptical about Henning Makholm's answer...

Comment: @Vladimir: If you're going to be super-pedantic, a contravariant functor is *not a functor at all*; instead, it is a different kind of gadget with a similar definition as functor, except you instead have the axiom $F(fg) = F(g) F(f)$.

Comment: Yes, but the point is that the correct casting back and forth from contravariant functor to covariant functors is done by oping the domain, not the codomain.

Comment: @Vladimir: "Correct" is too strong. "The usual convention" is more accurate.

Comment: It should definitely be "the preferred convention" at least -- in fact I think it's always "the better convention": otherwise the casting doesn't extend to natural transformations, hence to functor categories, which is why it really should be "correct". Are there theorems or arguments where it is more convenient to consistently use the other convention instead of the "correct" one?

Answer (score 9):

$-^{\rm op}$ is a self-inverse functor $\mathbf{Cat}\to\mathbf{Cat}$, so whenever you have an $F:\mathcal C\to\mathcal D$, you will also have $F^{\rm op}:\mathcal C^{\rm op}\to\mathcal D^{\rm op}$ simply by changing how you label things. In many contexts it doesn't even pay do distinguish strictly between $F$ and $F^{\rm op}$, and we can say they are simply two ways of looking at the same functor.

Since $-^{\rm op}$ is self-inverse, we have $(\mathcal C^{\rm op})^{\rm op}=\mathcal C$, so if we have $G:\mathcal C^{\rm op}\to\mathcal D$ we can also look at this as $G^{\rm op}:\mathcal C\to\mathcal D^{\rm op}$ -- and again there is often no need to distinguish strictly between these.

In sum, a covariant functor can be viewed either as $\mathcal C\to\mathcal D$ or as $\mathcal C^{\rm op}\to\mathcal D^{\rm op}$.

A "contravariant functor" from $\mathcal C$ to $\mathcal D$ is the same as an ordinary functor $\mathcal C^{\rm op}\to\mathcal D$ or $\mathcal C\to\mathcal D^{\rm op}$; these two descriptions are equivalent.

Comment: Are $[\mathcal{C}^{\text{op}},\mathcal{D}]$ and $[\mathcal{C},\mathcal{D}^{\text{op}}]$ the same categories?

Comment: @newincategories: No -- they are opposites (the natural transformations go in the opposite directions).

Comment: This is a misleading answer. The statements of major theorems about computing covariant functors extend to statements about contravariant functors only when you consider a contravariant functor as $\mathcal C^{op}\to\mathcal D$.

Comment: @VladimirSotirov: You're welcome to write your own answer where you explain what you think is _right_, instead of just denouncing something as _wrong_. Especially, it would it would be useful to have something concrete instead of nebulous descriptions such as "the statements of major theorems". You claim there are differences -- very well, _show them_, so a reader can _know_ rather than have to _trust_ one response over another!

Comment: E.g. every fact (except the self-dual ones) at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functor_category is true for contravariant functors considered as $\mathcal C^{op}\to\mathcal D$ but false as functors $\mathcal C\to\mathcal D^{op}$.

Comment: @HenningMakholm you are the one with the "nebulous" claim that an existing distinction can be ignored "often" and "in many contexts" without bothering to explain why that is the case or giving any guidance for the reader on how to tell if they are in such a context or not.

Comment: @VladimirSotirov: You seem to be better informed about these matters than I am. Why are you keeping your knowledge to yourself such that I and the OP both have to keep guessing about what the cases you're speaking about are? Again, I think you should write an answer setting things _right_ instead of just complaining about things that are _wrong_. **You're** not giving any guidance to the reader either -- I have given all I have; if you have something to offer that is better than my answer, don't keep it to yourself!

Comment: @VladimirSotirov your claim is nothing but a tautology: all statements by the wikipedia link produce dual statements for "contravariant" functors $\mathcal{C}\to\mathcal{D}^{op}$ (with having the isomorphism $[{\mathcal{C}^{op}},\mathcal{D}]\cong[{\mathcal{C}},{\mathcal{D}^{op}}]^{op}$ in mind).

Comment: @HenningMakholm I might have written an answer of my own if you had bothered to ask without patronizing me. The OP seems satisfied by my comment, and you keep trying to shame me into writing an answer while either stupidly or willfully ignoring the substance of what I've already written (it's major theorems *for computing functors*, it's the ones on the wikipedia page I linked, I said your answer was "misleading", not "wrong"). Be very surprised if I ever answer a question you ask after this hissy fit.

Comment: I am very confused. Sorry I have not accepted your answer, @Henning Makholm, but I really don't think I am in a position to judge it...

Comment: @newincategories: I've set a bounty on the question; hopefully that will attract some knowledgeable persons who can put things right better than I can.

Answer (score 3):

The phrase *"a functor from $\mathcal{C}^{op}$ to $\mathcal{D}$ **is the same as** a functor from $\mathcal{C}$ to $\mathcal{D}^{op}$"* means that there exists an isomorphism of categories:
$$
[{\mathcal{C}^{op}},\mathcal{D}]\cong[{\mathcal{C}},{\mathcal{D}^{op}}]^{op}.
$$
The phrase *"a functor from $\mathcal{C}^{op}$ to $\mathcal{D}^{op}$ **is the same as** a functor from $\mathcal{C}$ to $\mathcal{D}$"* means that there exists an isomorphism of categories:
$$
[{\mathcal{C}^{op}},\mathcal{D}^{op}]\cong[{\mathcal{C}},{\mathcal{D}}]^{op}.
$$
You can find an exact description of such isomorphism in [my answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1673431/leinster-question-on-isomorphic-functor-categories/1673474#1673474). It's easy to obtain the first isomorphism from the second by replacing $\mathcal{D}$ to $\mathcal{D}^{op}$.

Comment: The phrases still make sense even when the functor categories don't exist, so it cannot possibly mean there is an isomorphism of categories. Also, this does not at all address the original question of how to distinguish between the $\mathcal C^{op}\to\mathcal D$ and its opposite $\mathcal C\to\mathcal D^{op}$ except in misleadingly suggesting they are "the same".

Comment: @VladimirSotirov Seems that you are confused with the basic definitions of category theory. Functor categories _always_ exist (but they may not be _locally small_). I also disagree with you second statement: I think my answer gives enough information to understand "all that jazz". Also I think that HenningMakholm's answer is also useful, and your cavils are useless.

Comment: functor categories always exist only if you give up having a category of ALL sets and allow yourself only to have categories of $\mathscr U$-small sets for some universe $\mathscr U$ (and even then, you need to further assume that every set is contained in some universe). Either way, your claim depends on having a particular non-standard(!) foundation of mathematics *and* on giving up the category of all sets. Also, nobody cares what you think is useful or useless, the math speaks for itself.

Comment: @VladimirSotirov As I thought, you don't understand basics of category theory. Having a category of all sets does not contradict with existence of functor categories. Besides that, the fact that you don't care what I consider useful or useless doesn't imply that nobody doesn't care.

Comment: If you have a category of ALL sets, then its objects cannot form a set by Russel's paradox. So (at least if you are doing this with first-order logic) you need to introduce some notion of class distinct from the notion of a set, then in order to have all functor categories (e.g. the functor category from the wide discrete subcategory of sets to itself), the question becomes whether for any two classes you can form the class of all class functions between them. To do that you'll need to make classes objects of your theory, so renaming class->large set and set->small set recovers the problem.

Comment: @VladimirSotirov I still don't see the problem. Functions between classes form _conglomerates_.

Comment: Rename conglomerates to HUGE SETS, classes to Large sets. Then Large sets are not a set theory of the same kind as sets (at least the way the joy of cats sets them up), but HUGE SETS are, so you are now lacking a category of all HUGE SETS, i.e. a category of conglomerates unless you set up another fancy word for even larger sets, but you'll never stop is the point. If you rename your sets with some other fancy word, you also have to change the name in the problem of constructing a category of all sets...

Comment: @VladimirSotirov One very good reason for adopting Grothendieck's axiom of universes is that it allows one to make statements like the one in Oskar's answer, i.e. to replace vague statements like "a functor $\mathcal{C}^{\text{op}}\to\mathcal{D}$ is the same as a functor $\mathcal{C}\to \mathcal{D}^{\text{op}}$" with precise statements like "the functor category $[\mathcal{C}^{\text{op}},\mathcal{D}]$ is isomorphic to the opposite of the functor category $[\mathcal{C},\mathcal{D}^{\text{op}}]$".

Comment: On a larger scale, the same principle allowed Grothendieck to produce SGA without introducing technical caveats everywhere. Set theorists can give many other reasons for "believing in" a proper class of inaccessible cardinals, and much stronger hypotheses. The math speaks for itself! But even if you have qualms about adopting the axiom of universes, would you still take issue with Oskar's answer if it was edited to include the phrase "whenever these functor categories exist."? Perhaps it would be better to replace the phrase "means that" with "is justified because"?

Comment: @AlexKruckman a) the correct statement is that a functor and its opposite are determined by the same data, not that they are the same: a functor by definition already comes with the data of its domain and codomain; b) the justification of the fact that a functor and its opposite are given by the same data does not in any way depend on functor categories although the fact itself (not the justification) can be expressed using functor categories whenever they exist; c) i object to the tacit restriction of the definition of category to exclude the category of ALL sets, not to the use of universes.

Comment: @VladimirSotirov In my view, simply being determined by the same data is not enough to say (in a category theoretic context) that two objects are "the same". Rather, such a statement should be justified by some equivalence of categories. For example, given a poset $P$ with all finite meets, we may also regard $P$ as a semilattice. But while this poset and this semilattice are certainly determined by the same data, they are not "the same": the order-preserving maps out of $P$ (even to other posets with all finite meets) are different than the semilattice homomorphisms out of $P$.

Comment: On the other hand, I have no qualms about saying that a Stone space is "the same" as its Boolean algebra of clopen sets, because of Stone duality (though they are different sorts of objects entirely). It is in this sense that a functor $C\to D^{\text{op}}$ is the same as a functor $C^{\text{op}}\to C$. Of course, here I'm explaining my view about the proper meaning of the vague term "the same" in category theoretic contexts, and there's plenty of room to disagree. With Henning, I encourage you to write your own answer explaining your view, which obviously differs from mine and Oskar's.

Comment: Gentlemen, the exchange is becoming a bit too personal. I am obviously unable to arbitrate the mathematical disagreements, but I want to remind you of the *be nice* -policy.

Comment: To repeat the substance of my deleted comment: it is an abuse of terminology to assert that objects are "the same" instead of "equivalent" (or even worse: "the same" instead of "dual") when their categories are equivalent (respectively dual).

Comment: @Vladimir: You're entitled to your opinion, of course -- in my opinion, in many (possibly even *most*) cases "equivalent" is a better notion of sameness than "isomorphic", and "isomorphic" is a better notion than "equal".

Comment: Better notions of sameness: yes, but still distinct notions with equality primal in every logical system I am aware of.

Comment: @Vladimir: That's because, AFAIK, the notion of wanting to do without equality is relatively new, and a means of *how* we could do without is cutting edge research. e.g. except for equal-by-definition, homotopy type theory replaces equality with something that is basically homotopy equivalence.

Comment: @Hurkyl even in (univalent) homotopy type theory (according to the hott book at least) equality is asserted to be equivalent to equivalence, not equal to it, so the two notions begin as distinct and collapse after the fact, but only in the very particular sense of being able to shift witnesses of equivalence to witnesses of equality (plus equivalence is defined in terms of equality in the beginning). the fact that doing away with equality in favor of equivalence is cutting-edge research i take as another reason to maintain the distinction...

Answer (score 0):

In your example, the answer is yes. Your functor can be viewed as a contravariant functor $ \mathcal{C} \to \mathcal{D} $ *or* a covariant functor $ \mathcal{C}^\text{op} \to \mathcal{D} $ or a covariant functor $ \mathcal{C} \to \mathcal{D}^\text{op} $.

None of these is wrong, and you can view your functor in any of these ways.